# scoping the self in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a curious question, that I can't quite verbalize in programmer-speak, because the google searches are not being useful.

Let's say you have a block like

```
def foo
 a = biz.bar
 b = biz.rab
end
```

Is there a way that I could make it so I don't have to continuously repeat bar. ? Rather, I'd like to let ruby know that in a certain block, the current value of self is biz.

How would you go about doing that?

So, it would look something like

```
def foo
 #do something here 
  a = bar
  b = rab
 #end
  a #=> biz.bar
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `Object#instance_eval`, although it's a tad hacky and probably not good style. Example:

```
def foo
  biz.instance_eval do
    a = bar
    b = rab
    a
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that the normal block scoping rules apply, so you can't see `a` from outside the block if it didn't exist there before the block started.